# How do I add colour code to Matplotlib legend

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to add a legend to a matplotlib radar/polar graph.  I am very new to matplotlib so please excuse the code.  I also expect this is very simple but I've been at it an hour and got nowhere.

I have the following which produces a list of labels in the bottom left corner but whenever I try to add handles to give the color representing the label I lose the legend.

```
    # Set color of axes
    plt.rc('axes', linewidth=0.5, edgecolor="#888888")

    # Create polar plot
    ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

    # Set clockwise rotation. That is:
    ax.set_theta_offset(pi / 2)
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

    # Set position of y-labels
    ax.set_rlabel_position(0)

    # Set color and linestyle of grid
    ax.xaxis.grid(True, color="#888888", linestyle='solid', linewidth=0.5)
    ax.yaxis.grid(True, color="#888888", linestyle='solid', linewidth=0.5)

    # Plot data
    ax.plot(x_as, values, linewidth=0, linestyle='solid', zorder=3)

    # Fill area
    ax.fill(x_as, values, 'r', alpha=0.3)

    plt.legend(labels=[self.get_object().name], loc=(-.42,-.13))
    if not self.get_object().subscription is None:
        if self.get_object().subscription.benchmark:
            bx = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
            bx.plot(x_as, baseline, linewidth=0, linestyle='solid', zorder=3)
            bx.fill(x_as, baseline, 'b', alpha=0.3)
            plt.legend(labels=[self.get_object().name, 'Benchmark'], loc=(-.42,-.13))
```

I believe I need

```
plt.lengend(handles=[some list], labels=[self.get_object().name, 'Benchmark'], loc=(-.42,-.13))
```

I do not understand what the list of `handles` should be and I've tried a number of things, including `[ax, bx]`, `[ax.plt(), bx.plt()]`, `['r', 'b']`

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html):

> **handles** : sequence of Artist, optional
>
> A list of Artists (lines, patches) to be added to the legend. Use this together with labels, if you need full control on what is shown
>   in the legend and the automatic mechanism described above is not
>   sufficient.
>
> The length of handles and labels should be the same in this case. If they are not, they are truncated to the smaller length.

`plt.plot` returns a list a line2D objects which is what you need to pass to `plt.legend()`. Therefore a simplified example is as follows:

```
labels = ["Line 1", "Line 2"]

lines1, = plt.plot([1,2,3])
lines2, = plt.plot([3,2,1])

handles = [lines1, lines2]

plt.legend(handles, labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @DavidG, it was the comma I kept missing out in `line1, = plt.plot(...)`